# How to show that S is not linear

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> To show a transformation is not linear, it is enough to find a counter example to one of
>   the linearity properties. Thus, you may choose specific vectors/scalars and show one of
>   the two properties does not hold. Let $S : \mathbb{R}^2 → \mathbb{R}^2
> $ be defined by $S(u) = u + e_1$. Find a
>   counterexample that shows S is **not** linear

I'm not sure how exactly to show this is not linear using the properties of a linear transformation that i have

Comment: That is to say:  I take your definition to mean that $S(x,y)=(x+1,y)$.

Comment: $S(u + 1, v) = S(0) = \begin{bmatrix}0 + 1\\0\end{bmatrix} \ne 0 \implies$ **not** linear correct?

Comment: First row of what?  People often use $e_i$ to denote the "standard basis".  Thus $e_1=(1,0)\;\&\;e_2=(0,1)$.  (this generalizes to $\mathbb R^n$).

Comment: My argument worked with my interpretation of the question.  I am assuming that $S(x,y)=(x+1,y)$.  If you meant something different, then my argument may not apply.

Comment: $\mathbb R^2$ is not a matrix!  I don't know what you think a matrix is. I think you need to go back to your text and do some reading.

Comment: No. $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear space generated by $n$ vectors, which are elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are vectors. $\mathbb{R}^n$ itself is not a vector.

Comment: $\mathbb R^2$ is the set of all ordered pairs $(x_1,x_2)$ where $x_i\in \mathbb R$.  Any given such pair is certainly a vector, but $\mathbb R^2$ is the collection of all such vectors.  It's usually depicted as the Cartesian Plane.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42198/discussion-on-question-by-yusha-how-to-show-that-s-is-not-linear). I left some of the comments that I think were explaining a point. For the rest I refer you to the chatroom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linear map $S: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ satisfies the property $S(ru)=rS(u)$ for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$ and $u \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Let $r=0$ and we get as a special case that $S(0)=0$. However, if $S(u)=u+e_1$, then $S(0)=e_1$. Hence, your map is linear if and only if $e_1=0$.